# Javascript loop clicker

Tags: javascript, closures, pause

I'm trying to make a javascript script running from the urlbar which for each row on a specific page clicks a button (allowing me to change a certain value), then edit that value, then click that button again to confirm. I'm running into a lot of trouble with simultaneity, as it seems to wait to do the first click 5000 ms even tho it's not being told to pause. didn't do the same when i tested the structure replacing things in between pauses with rando alerts

The reason for the pauses is bc there's a short loading animation during which I can't execute code. Anything glaringly wrong in this as-is? I know there's funky stuff w/ closure, but I thought by busywaiting i could get past it but its not.

```
function pause(milliseconds) {
    var dt = new Date();
    while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
}
var q=document.getElementById("MainContent_gvProducts").children[0];
var l=q.children.length;

for(i=1;i<l;i++){
    q.children[i].children[0].children[0].click();
    pause(5000);
    var x=q.children[i].children[7].children[0].value;
    pause(1);
    x=math.round(x);
    pause(5000);
    q.children[i].children[0].children[0].click();
    pause(5000);
}
```

Comment: the frontend will be rendered after those codes return. Not as what you think (click -> render->pause->click->render->pause). setTimeOut  may meet your requirements.

Comment: @Sphinx i tried that but it didn't play nice with the forloop, since it ran each at once. What do u mean it'll b rendered after the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pause` function seems very hacky.
You should use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead, or something similar.

If you can afford to use the latest JS tech, I'd recommand creating a `promise` with a timeout and using async/await, with something like this :

```
async function pause(t = 1000) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true)
        }, t)
    })
}

for(i=1;i<l;i++){
    q.children[i].children[0].children[0].click();
    await pause(1000)
    var x=q.children[i].children[7].children[0].value;
    pause(1);
    x=math.round(x);
    await pause(5000);
    q.children[i].children[0].children[0].click();
    await pause(5000);
}
```

Note : your `for` loop must be placed in an `async` function.